# iRobot Create 2 to Vacuum (2)?

Tags: irobot-create

Does the Create 2 have firmware support (navigation, brush & fan control, ...) to support the vacuum functionality?

Can I use parts from my 655 or 805 Roomba to convert the Create 2 back to a vacuum?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and yes.  The Create2 has the same firmware as any other 600 series Roomba.  There is nothing preventing you from replacing the missing components to have a functional vacuum.